# Check if logical colon is typed, not if physical shift+semicolon key combination was pressed

Tags: javafx

In a JavaFX 11 key event handler, when I check the event's key code, how can I check logically for the colon character, no matter which key combination on whatever keyboard layout means a colon?  My application must respond to certain characters being input on the keyboard, where a colon means a certain command.

When I type colon (Shift+semicolon on the U.S. keyboard), the key code is not `KeyCode.COLON` but rather `KeyCode.SEMICOLON` with the modifier `shift: true`. This is the case for both `KeyPressed` and `KeyTyped`.

I want my listener to check for the resulting character, not the particular key combination that produced that character. Otherwise, my listener may fail on other keyboard layouts besides U.S.

Comment: [getCharacter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCharacter--)

Answer (score 0):

KeyTyped events contain the character that was typed.

```
boolean typedAColon = ":".equals(event.getCharacter())
```